# Why should a 'Restful' API return the entire request payload in the response?

Tags: rest, api, http

I am working with an API (which is meant to be restful) which is returning the entire request in the response, are there any reasons for doing this? As far as I can see it would never be useful as the one calling the API already has that information, wouldn't it be cleaner and faster to not include it?

Comment: Debugging purposes? I have written stateless protocols before (not REST APIs) that copy input values in responses, especially if an error occurs. Comes in handy when the traffic is being logged.

Comment: I prefer logging request to something other service (using fluentd for example) instead of replaying request to the client.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the entire request'? All request headers? The complete URL? How is this data included in the response?